# using arm_navigation_msgs/GetMotionPlan: what setup/nodes are required to receive trajectories programatically

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, arm-navigation, ompl-planning, jointtrajectory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been following the ompl tutorials listed [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials/Calling%20the%20joint%20space%20planner)
and it all seems fairly straightforward except that it doesn't seem that having the ompl_planning node alone would be sufficient to generate the trajectory required.

I've completed the warehouse viewer example for my robot and I'd like to use the solutions that it shows within my own nodes (without the graphical visualisation) using the [MotionPlanRequest](http://ros.org/doc/api/arm_navigation_msgs/html/msg/MotionPlanRequest.html) interface of the GetMotionPlan.srv

What other nodes are required to allow the ompl_planning node to generate a path. (Just the bare bones, not much collision checking except for self collision). I think the nodes listed in the  X_arm_navigation.launch may be required but I dont want to overcomplicate things at this stage.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58061/using-arm_navigation_msgs/getmotionplan:-what-setup/nodes-are-required-to-receive-trajectories-programatically/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would also need to setup an **environment_server** (package **planning_environment**), for keeping track of the robot state. If you're only interested in self-collision checking, make sure that the use_collision_map parameter is set to false.

If you plan on specifying task-space goal configurations, you should also set up an inverse kinematics service/plugin.

Depending on which planners you use, the output might not be a smooth motion, nor properly parameterized in time. Trajectory filters (smoothers, shortcutters) come in handy for this. Of course, once you bundle OMPL + environment_server + IK + tajectory_filters, you have thrown most of arm_navigation in, which is what you're trying to avoid. At any rate, I hope this post helps at least to determine what functionalities won't be available in minimal setups.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-03-18**:
Thanks Aldolfo, having most of the arm_navigation_stack going is where I'm at now. Followed a few of your previous questions to get there. I been able to call the ompl_planning service but haven't been able to successfully get a response. I've a few related other questions I'd appreciate your help